# Android - How to create action bar like WhatsApp chat?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to create `Actionbar` or `Tollbar` whatever it is in my app. I did my best to create the similar as below but the results are very bad so its better not to share here:

[image]

And remember that the following red rectangular area is clickable having the ripple effect:

[image]

Is that possible with `Actionbar`, if no then is this possible with `Toolbar`, if no then is that fine to create it with `constraint` or `relative` layout?

I did my best but i am failed to do so with `Actionbar` and `Toolbar`. Thanks !!!

Comment: I really didn't understand your question. If you want to same then use custom toolbar. Simple! There are many ways to implement this kind of layout

Comment: Can we do it with `ActionBar`?

Comment: Can you share a single way so that i will read to get the idea at least

Comment: Yes!, you can, as `Toolbar` is also a `ViewGroup`, add TextViews and a RoundedImageView in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and add that LinearLayout inside Toolbar & you are good to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a layout for toolbar then you can add this layout as a child to the toolbar. Don't forget to set `contentInsetStart` attribute of the toolbar to 0dp. For ripple effect you can use a button with background of `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`.